# how to hide and show sidenavigation panel in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have used ng-include for adding html, In included html i have side navigation panel include,This side navigation include i want to  show in one html and not in second html , how i can do it ?

MY include

```
<div ng-include src="'template/includeGallery.html'"  id="angularGallery" ng-controller="galleryCtrl as vm"  
                ng-show="vm.showGallery" resize>
</div>
```

includeGallery.html as

```
<div class="gallery">
                <div class="close" ng-click="vm.closeGallery()">
                    <img src="../images/closeimage.png" class="close-img">
                </div>
                <!-- Gallery start -->  

               <div  ng-include src="'view/sidepanel.html'">
          </div>
 </div>
```

In above code i want to show  `ng-include src="'view/sidepanel.html'">` in one html page and i dont want want show in second html both have different controller .

Both html have different controller .

Comment: which router are you using?

Comment: i am using $routeProvider.

Comment: I think, its a wrong way to do that .

Comment: Can u suggest me , how i can proceed this one ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ng-show here :

Initialize one status variable from controller to ensure that you want to show or not.

```
$scope.status = true;
```

Then in your view :

```
<div ng-show="status" ng-include src="'template/includeGallery.html'"  id="angularGallery" ng-controller="galleryCtrl as vm"  
                ng-show="vm.showGallery" resize>
</div>
```

Comment: i already did but problem is  ng-include src="'template/includeGallery.html'" has one more included html that i want hide in second html which has different controller .

Comment: So try this in second then, otherwise you can utilize ng-if also.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller where you don't want to include the file, take a `flag`, make it true and add `ng-if` condition where you are including the partial,

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {

    vm.to_display = true;

    }

])
```

includeGallery.html as

```
<div class="gallery">
                <div class="close" ng-click="vm.closeGallery()">
                    <img src="../images/closeimage.png" class="close-img">
                </div>
                <!-- Gallery start -->  

               <div  ng-if = "vm.to_display" ng-include src="'view/sidepanel.html'">
          </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: ok you have `controller-as` , change `vm.to_display = true`, in view, 
`ng-if = "vm.to_display"`

Comment: change to the variable which you used in controller as

Comment: In one controller its working fine but in second controller its not working .

Comment: what is the second controller, it might have other `controller-as`, paste the second controller code

Comment: does your second controller also uses `controller-as` syntax